# How do I console.log a changed state in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm new to React and am working on someone else's code (thrown in the deep end).

There is a simple button has a `handleClick()` handler. I want to increment a specific state by 1.

To that effect I have tried:

```
state = {
  page: 0,
}

  handleClick() {

    this.setState(state => ({
      page: state.page + 1
    }))

    console.log(page)
  }
```

but this just produces a `page is not defined` error.

I've tried various combinations of the above, eg `console.log(state.page)`, `page: page + 1`, etc but don't get any results.

Would anyone know how I could console log to test if the state is updating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass a callback function to you're `this.setState` which will be invoked after state is updated. Something like below:

```
this.setState(state => ({
      page: state.page + 1
    }), () => console.log(this.state) )
```

sample [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/setstate-callback-jd5b2)

Comment: This is the way (using setState callback function).

Comment: In react functional component, use additional 'useEffect' hook

Answer (score 1):

You should use a callback to see the changed state, because, **setState** is asynchronous in React. According to the documentation:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

```
 handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.page)
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to page directly. You must use a `this.state` reference. Try:

```
  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      page: state.page + 1
    }))
    console.log(this.state.page)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` in React is an asynchronous method, hence when you try to console the updated state just after updating it, the `console.log` will provide you the previous state only. So to counter you need to console the state in a callback function of `setState` like this:

```
handleClick() {

    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page + 1
    }, () => {
       console.log(this.state.page)
    })
}
```

Now `console.log` will give you the updated state.

Answer (score 0):

To console.log state in a React functional component, use additional '**useEffect**' hook.

```
useEffect(() => console.log(<state name>), [<state name>]);
```